# Camel Upgrade 2.22 breaks Apache CXF endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf

I have upgraded Camel 2.22. along with CXF version 3.2.5,Spring boot 2.04.RELEASE
When I start my application I can't see any errors but the can't access endpoints anymore

below is the code:

1) Camel route:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="porEndpoint" address="/por/" serviceClass="x.y.z.service.PorService" publishedEndpointUrl="">
        <cxf:binding>
            <soap:soapBinding version="1.2"/>
        </cxf:binding>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

2) Properties:
cxf.path=/services
server.servlet.context-path=/fuse-test

3)This URL worked fine earlier :http://localhost:8080/fuse-test/services/por?wsdl

I have enabled trace at context level and log mode as debug but I can't find any errors apart from :
**o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Ignoring PartialResultException**

Answer (score 2):

camel-cxf(v 3.2.5) somehow doesn't include the cxf spring boot. After adding the below dependency the endpoint is available

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you sir are a life saver!